# Как в jquery отловить сложные селекторы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть собственно селекторы вот такого вида:

```
#checkbox1:checked + .checkbox-label
```

Как их выбрать с помощью jquery ? 
Код такого вида не работает:

```
$('#checkbox1:checked + .checkbox-label').css({
// здесь провожу манипуляции с css
})
```

Comment: А для чего, собственно, это делать, если в css все стили можно описать?

Comment: И, кстати, ваш код рабочий. Просто его применять нужно при каждой манипуляции с чекбоксами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий пример по ссылке [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6vmmbyb/2/)

Может не работать из-за того, что не найдено ни одного соответствующего элемента. Для того, чтобы понять почему не работает нужна соответствующая часть HTML.

Поясню по `#checkbox1:checked + .checkbox-label`. Это селектор (“prev + next”). Он ищет элемент "next", который находятся после элемента "prev" в пределах общего "родителя".

Т.е. если разместить prev и next в разных блоках код не сработает.

Comment: мне просто нужно в определенный момент поменять стили этого блока

Comment: Для примера создал два события: при нажатии кнопки и при изменении статуса checkbox. Смотрите [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/w6vmmbyb/3/)

Comment: во  спасибо! теперь понял :)